# Drag and drop - user interface query

Tags: c#, user-interface, drag-and-drop

c# winforms  -I am trying to improve my app by having some drag drop functionality. - This is all working fine - but i would like to show a "Box" with text such as "Drop Here" when the form is dragged over as a target for the drop. i can get the picture box to display in that manner when drag enters the form, however the picture box will not accept the drop.

The drop data will either be a file or a web address - again i can manage the identification of that, the only thing i need to do is to get the picture box to accept the drop, and that does not appear to be possible

Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple example, place a Label on top of a TextBox. Set visibility of the Label to false.

- In DragEnter event of the TextBox, set the label Visible to true
- In DragLeave event of the TextBox, set the label Visible to false
- In DragDrop event of the TextBox, set the label Visible to false

Here the TextBox name is FolderTextBox and our label is ShowHelpLabel.

```
private void FolderTextBox_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
    {
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
        ShowHelpLabel.Visible = true;
    }
}

private void FolderTextBox_DragLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ShowHelpLabel.Visible = false;
}

private void FolderTextBox_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    var droppedData = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);

    if (!Directory.Exists(droppedData[0])) return;
    ShowHelpLabel.Visible = false;
    FolderTextBox.Text = droppedData[0];
}
```

[Full source](https://github.com/karenpayneoregon/windows-forms-csharp/tree/Version3/RemoveMarkOfWeb) for above which is a simple utility.

[image]